# "Pioppetta" è una variante regionale di "pioppeto"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Il treno partí e Milton lo seguí con lo sguardo fino alla svolta. Voleva ripigliarlo dopo il ponte, rincorrendone il pennacchio di fumo al di sopra delle interminabili **pioppette** dell’oltrefiume, ma Giorgio lo spinse ai cancelli. «Andiamo a giocare a biliardo».

La mia domanda è su queste "pioppette" che appaiono in questo brano. Non ho trovato il termine "pioppetta" in nessun dizionario, ma sí "pioppeto". Per esempio, sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pioppeto) si legge

> **pioppéto** s. m. [der. di *pioppo*; cfr. lat. *populetum*, der. di *popŭlus* «pioppo»]. – Bosco spontaneo, o piantagione artificiale, di pioppi.

Mi chiedo se il vocabolo "pioppetta" sia una variante regionale di "pioppeto".

**Aggiornamento:**

Infatti il termine "pioppeta", con una sola "t" (forse non è la stessa cosa), appare più avanti nel libro:

> Tossí forte, senza precauzioni, poi prese a retrocedere carponi verso la falda della collina. Appena fu in una **pioppeta**  si alzò su tutta la persona, crocchiando come una canna.

In questo caso sembra riferirsi a un bosco.

Comment: Su Treccani come sinonimo di genere femminile di pioppeto si trova [pioppaia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pioppeto_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/). Secondo me pioppeta viene usata come ad esempio pineta.

Comment: @abarisone: Infatti sul testo di Fenoglio appare "pioppette" con la doppia "t". Sono io che ho fatto un pasticcio togliendo una "t" nella versione precedente della domanda.

Comment: Infatti su [questo sito web](http://www.lavalledelmetauro.it/contenuti/beni-ambientali/scheda/3775.html) appare "pioppeta" (con una sola "t") con chiaramente il significato di "bosco di pioppi".

Comment: Non sarà un refuso?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket: Non lo so: sono andata in Piemonte e ho osservato che fanno le doppie in un modo molto diverso dal resto dell'Italia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La parola pioppa al femminile viene usata a volte come sinonimo di pioppo, come definito qui nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pioppa/).

Una pioppetta dunque non è altro che un piccolo pioppo, e nel testo ci si riferisce ad una ampia distesa di tali alberi oltre il fiume.

Dato che Milton vede il fumo del treno sopra le pioppette, si tratta certamente di singoli alberi, anche se numerosi, e non di diversi pioppeti.